# Processor Intel Pentium 4 3.40 Ghz can run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bit?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, 64-bit, intel-pentium

Does the PC with the specs below can run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 bit ?

- Pentium 4 3.40 GHz, 65 nm Cedar Mill
- Socket LGA775
- 2 GB DDR2 RAM
- 160 GB Hard drive
- nvidia  6500  GT video

The min sys req for Ubuntu18.04 LTS require at least 2 GHz processor, but it doesnt say if single-core processors are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run OK.  I have Ubuntu 18 in a VM with 2 GB of memory, it easily fits in under 50 GB, and I have a 2 core CPU.  The post below says OK for 1 core. A number of YES, but try it out comments. The CPU supports 64-bit operating systems

Ubuntu 18 comes in 32-bit if you need to do that.

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/linux-for-laptop-with-single-core-cpu/97132